# Looking for small pixel font

Tags: fonts

I'm looking for a small pixel font that has western, european and cyrillic characters, something similar in look to the SMALL FONTS font found in windows (around 6/7px)

It's for a retro looking videogame so must be small clean pixels.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something retro I would suggest a bitmap type font: http://www.dafont.com/bitmap.php

This thread might be relevant for best font for limited space: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/what-is-the-best-font-for-extremely-limited-space-i-e-will-fit-the-most-readab

This person answered with Tahoma font which supports cyrillic characters.

Comment: Thanks, but the smallest tahoma font is too big for me. My game is a very small resolution (320x240)

Comment: You can make the font any size? http://jsfiddle.net/Lt2csqdu/. For something so small look at the bitmap fonts. I am not sure if they would have all the characters you need.